# combining objects and arrays with condition in powershell

Tags: powershell

My data($messages) looks like this

```
Source: sourceA
Message : {@{messagetext = abc;publishedtime = 10/5/2020}, @{messagetext = def;publishedtime = 10/12/2020}
```

I am trying to filter the message by displaying only messages that happened from last week until now then combining it with the source property. It is possible that a source may have multiple lines if several publishedtime happened last week.

```
$filterDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)    
$messages | select source, @{n='messagetext' ; e={???}} , @{n='publishedtime' ; e={???}}
```

I am lost on how to add the calculated property with the condition. I was also thinking if this could be done with a loop.

I also tried the following but having some errors

```
$Messages | Where-Object {([DateTime]($_.messages).publishedtime).ToUniversalTime() -ge $filterDate} but having some error
```

Comment: In order to debug the date issue, please [edit] the question and add your system locale (use Get-WinSystemLocale to find out) as well as a few sample dates. Also, what error, exactly, do you get? The error likely contains hints about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a calculated property. First filter the `$messages` collection by date. Like so,

```
$filterDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
$lastWeek = $messages | ? { $_.PublishedTime -ge $filterDate }
```

Now the `$lastWeek` collection contains only messages that were published within a week. Depending on the exact format of `PublishedTime` and your locale settings, it might need to be parsed as a date. If that's the case, please edit the question and show a few examples of actual data. Sanitize the messages if needed.

Comment: Publishedtime is a member of $messages.message

Comment: @Dumont Then the filter is akin to `? { $_.Message.PublishedTime ...} `

Answer (score 1):

I think you should always compare dates to **dates**, and not compare a datetime object to a **string**, especially since in your question it is unclear what exact format the date is in.
Probably the format used is `'M/d/yyyy'`, but it could just aswell be `'d/M/yyyy'` or even `'MM/d/yyyy'`

```
$dateFormat = 'M/d/yyyy'  # <-- this is unclear in the question, could also be 'd/M/yyyy' or 'MM/d/yyyy'

# you can set the Time part to all zero, as the dates in the $Messages objects also do not have that
$filterDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).Date  
$Messages | Where-Object {[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Message.publishedtime, $dateFormat, $null) -ge $filterDate}
```